# Generic call to xml serialisation of a custom object

Tags: c#, xml

I'm writing this method that serialise an object to an xml document. I get no compile time error but it fails at runtime(InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.Linq.DataQuery....).  Any help will be highly appreciated.

```
public string CreateXML<T>(Object ClassObject)
    {
        XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();   


       System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(((T)ClassObject).GetType());

        using (MemoryStream xmlStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            xmlSerializer.Serialize(xmlStream, ClassObject);
            xmlStream.Position = 0;

            xmlDoc.Load(xmlStream);
            return xmlDoc.InnerXml;
        }

    }
```

Runtime error:
InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.Linq.DataQuery`1[LINQPad.User.tbl_car]' to type 'LINQPad.User.tbl_car'.

Comment: Just added full runtime error description to the original post

Comment: Meta: The method signature looks broken with that capital letter on `ClassObject`. And please for everything that is good and proper get rid of those comments. They're just cruft.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you pass object? Just change it to the generic type and should working fine:

```
public string CreateXML<T>(T ClassObject)
{
    XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();   //Represents an XML document, 
    // Initializes a new instance of the XmlDocument class.          
  //  XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(ClassObject.GetType());
    var  xmlSerializer = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
    // Creates a stream whose backing store is memory. 
    using (MemoryStream xmlStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        xmlSerializer.Serialize(xmlStream, ClassObject);
        xmlStream.Position = 0;
        //Loads the XML document from the specified string.
        xmlDoc.Load(xmlStream);
        return xmlDoc.InnerXml;
    }
   // return null;
}
```

Comment: I did just this but it does not solve the problem. see full runtime error in my initial post

Comment: The error is in your calling code. It probably shouldn't even compile with the actual generic parameter.

Comment: @bstenzel, you are correct. I call this with a collection of object and not an oject. (from t in t_cars where t.id>35 select t). There are more then 100 records.

Comment: @MeelfanBmfp there is no problem with this code, you should check the calling code and also add more details about class suppose to serialize it.

Answer (score 0):

Following Bstenzel very usefull remark, i now convert the result of my query to a DataTable as follow and now i get my xml out.

```
    public static class ToDataTableClass
{
    public static DataTable ToDataTable<T>(this List<T> items)
    {
        var tb = new DataTable(typeof(T).Name);
        //string tempHeaderString = "";

        PropertyInfo[] props = typeof(T).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);

        foreach (var prop in props)
        {
            tb.Columns.Add(prop.Name);
            //if (prop.PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Nullable<>))
            //{
            //    tempHeaderString = prop.Name;
            //}
            //else
            //{
            //        tb.Columns.Add(prop.Name, prop.PropertyType);
            //}
        }

        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            var values = new object[props.Length];
            for (var i = 0; i < props.Length; i++)
            {
                values[i] = props[i].GetValue(item, null);
            }

            tb.Rows.Add(values);
        }

        return tb;
    }
}
```